After switching languages from Arabic to English in iOS app, some views are flipped horizontally
In our iOS app, multiple languages are already supported. But there are one strange bug: After switching languages from Arabic to English, some views are flipped horizontally, which not look like right-to-left (RTL) text style, just flipped. But in Xcode's Debug view hierarchy, the views are not flipped horizontally, whose layout and display are correct, we don't know why. Screenshot as below:

The screenshot's controls are embedded in UIStackView which are embedded in UICollectionView.
We've already done some things on multiple languages support, like:
// Switch to specific language
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")

// Force LTR or RTL
let langDirection = Locale.characterDirection(forLanguage: langId)
if langDirection == .rightToLeft {
    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    UILabel.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    UITextField.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    UITextView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    UIButton.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    UIScrollView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    UITableView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    UICollectionView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
} else {
    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    UILabel.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    UITextField.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    UITextView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    UIButton.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    UIScrollView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    UITableView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    UICollectionView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
}

// After language switched, rebuild UITabBarController and its viewControllers

// Auto Layout's leftAnchor / rightAnchor has been changed to leadingAnchor / trailingAnchor

Any tips or answers would be greatly appreciated.

Why are you forcing right to left?  It is important that you use leading and trailing constraints, not left and right constraints in order for the layout to work correctly in both locales

@Paulw11 yeah, we've used leading and trailing constraints, but the problem also occurs

You need to provide a [mcve]
